# I want to write from 2nd row while writing DataFrame to csv file using Apache Spark (Scala API)

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While writing DataFrame to `csv` file using something like:

```
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("file.csv")
```

It is always writing from first row, but I want to write from second row. How can I write from second row?

Comment: Do you want to remove the first record?

Comment: No, Actually whenever I write data to csv file it is writing from first row of the file. But my requirement is to leave the first row empty and start writing data from second row in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform following steps to achieve that.

1. Get the first row object using `df.first()`.
2. Filter the original dataframe based on this row using `filter` method.
3. You can save the filtered dataframe to CSV using your code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Vinod, Thanks for your response.

Comment: Here, I don't wnat to change any of my data. I want to write the data as it is. Only problem is I want to write the data from 2nd row of the file and keep empty the first of the file.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question as dataframe has Row class. I will check and update the answer if I find a solution.